# Laravel - reading CSV file and insert into database row limit

Tags: php, json, laravel, csv, guzzle

From my controller, I convert each lines of the csv file contents into array using the below code:

```
    $csv = array_map('str_getcsv', file($request->file('file')));
    Log::info(sizeof($csv)); //9000 rows
```

and then I post the `$csv` using guzzle to my backend API server in JSON format.

From my API, I insert into my product table using the code:

```
    Log::info($sizeof($request->csv)); //500 rows
    Product::insert($request->csv);
```

However, seems like the maximum rows are capped at 500 rows, each time I import, even if I have 9,000 rows in my CSV file, it always insert only 500 rows.

Is there a limit to the max number of rows able to insert using `DB::insert` ? Or is it a default limit set by guzzle or laravel on the size of posted JSON?

thanks

Comment: "Is there a limit to the max number of rows able to insert using DB::insert ?" did you not check the input and found that it has 500 entry before the insert ? or did you only notice that 500 are inserted without any error ?